# Excel Row selection based on Top Values/Ranks

Tags: excel, row, rank

I am stuck on this and would love some help

Here is my table

| Product | Type | Ranking | Number of Columns Needed is 3 which is calculated formula |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gum | Wrigley | 4 | 3 |
| Candy | Skittles | 3 |  |
| Milk | Whole | 2 |  |
| Bread | Wheat | 1 |  |

I would like to select the top 3 rows (Amount of Rows) based on ranking and only the first two columns:

So end result would look like this:

| Product | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Gum | Wrigley |
| Candy | Skittles |
| Milk | Whole |

I tried everything to figure this out

Comment: Your question is not clear. Based on your data above, it looks like you have already solved it. You have a rank column, so just sort by that and select your first 3 rows.

Comment: I want to use the cell above the 3 in amount of rows

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to only view the top 3 rows then what you need is to filter your data to only use the top 3 (or any threshold) values.

You can find the filter option at the top right under the Home tab or you can use ctrl + shift + L and it will automatically show arrows at the top rows. Then you just need to click on the arrows and select Number Filters. Then you can select whichever element is most relevant to you

If what you want is to sort your data then you already have a column for ranking. All you need is to sort the data from high to low and BAMMM!!! you got your top rows

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing it. In cell `E2`:

```
=FILTER(A2:B5, ISNUMBER(XMATCH(C2:C5, LARGE(C2:C5,{1;2;3}))))
```

Assuming you want the top three rows based on the **Ranking** value. Notice, your input data is sorted, but in general, it maybe not be the case.

Here is the output:
[image: sample excel file]

You can replace the array with: `SEQUENCE(3,1)` for a more general case.

If your excel version has available the `DROP/CHOOSECOLS` functions then we can use `SORT`, then remove the last column, and finally select the first three rows:

```
=CHOOSEROWS(DROP(SORT(A2:C5,3, -1),,-1), SEQUENCE(3,1))
```

### Update

If you just need to select the first `n`-rows and just output the first two columns, then `LARGE/SORT` is not needed. Let's say you have the number of rows to show specified in a cell `F1`, then you can achieve it as follow:

Using `INDEX`:

```
=A2:INDEX(B2:B5,F1,1)
```

Using `FILTER`:

```
=FILTER(A2:B5, SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:B5),1) <= F1)
```

Using `CHOOSEROWS`:

```
=CHOOSEROWS(A2:B5, SEQUENCE(F1,1))
```

Comment: I think this gets me part way, the problem is I wont  know if it's the top 3 rows or the tp 12 rows.  Its a cell that I need to reference so it would have to be in the Large statement where it would somehow reference the number needed.

Comment: You can have the maximum number of large values to return specified in cell reference, so the value is not part of the formula, but instead a cell reference. For example: `FILTER(A2:B5, ISNUMBER(XMATCH(C2:C5, LARGE(C2:C5, SEQUENCE(F2,1)))))`you have it specified in cell `F2`. Please let me know if the solution provided respond to your question. Thanks

Comment: I am getting a #calc error, Does F2 have to be in the result, so I have a number in lets say G2 and that is the one I ref, so change it to G2 in the sequence statement?

Comment: @TGerischer for which approach are you getting `#CALC!` error? I am using your input data, are you using the same dataset? Do you have any excel version constraints? I don't follow you about your `F2`, `G2` comments, please would you rephrase it? or to update the question for a better understanding. My modification using `F2`, means it is an input parameter and yes, every time you change it, the result also changes.

Comment: See Above I changed the table

Comment: So you need just to select the rows based on a number that indicates how many rows to select from the beginning an this parameter should be in `G2`. Is it correct?

Comment: @TGerischer still I am not following you, do you mean column on this comment or row: "Number of Columns Needed is 3 which is the calculated formula" the output in your question is only the first two column. What is the role or **Ranking** column then? Please clarify that. Thanks

Comment: @TGerischer I updated my answer based on my understanding, but I am not 100% sure about your requirements.

Comment: Ok, so here is a better desc.  I have a formula that takes a sample size based on number of rows (done).  That would be 3 or it could be any number for that matter.  I have that populated in a cell.  Based on that I created a random generator (done) that gives me a values.  I then want to take the top 3 or top 20 or whatever the formula yields. So basically it's calculating the number of sample size I need and then I want to use that sample size to select random rows

Comment: @TGerischer I guess I am able to follow you, please did you see my update in my answer (Update section), I would say this is what are you looking for. Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Do you have an email and I can send you the spreadsheet

Comment: this is no how SO works, please update your question in a way we understand better the ask or even better formulate another question with your new requirement. This is a community knowledge base, so the information should be shared with the Community, not with specific people. You can try to share a shareable link to your file, but this is not really necessary, the content of the question should be enough.

Comment: Ok, I will try again.  I have data from A1:H125.  I have another column I to create a random number =IF(A1=0,0,INT(RAND()*(100-10)+10)), Column J =COUNTIF(A1:A125, "<> 0") and then column K is =ROUNDUP(IF(I1 < J2,1,J1/ 12),0).  So now I got a number, it could be any as you can see.  I want to select the rows that are calculated to get a random sample, so it would pull A1:H1 if that had the highest value for random etc.

Comment: @TGerischer I was trying to help you as much as I can, I haven't got a confirmation about if my updated answer works for your question or even the original one. You need to update the existing question if the scope is the same adding additional clarification, if not, then you need to post another question. My answer addresses to get the highest ranking values.